# использование runLater - многократный запуск графического интерфейса

Tags: java, javafx

есть класс который представляет собой Tray, в нем на SysTrayMenuItem навешан листенер("Этот листенер реализован в конструкоре Tray()):

```
item.addSysTrayMenuListener(new SysTrayMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void menuItemSelected(SysTrayMenuEvent sysTrayMenuEvent) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            new Window();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void iconLeftClicked(SysTrayMenuEvent sysTrayMenuEvent) {
                //
            }

            @Override
            public void iconLeftDoubleClicked(SysTrayMenuEvent sysTrayMenuEvent) {
                //
            }
        });
```

по нажатию этой кнопки в трее должно выскакивать окно с редактированием

в чем проблема: нажимаю на кнопку, окно открывается, закрываю окно, опять нажимаю в трее на кнопку, второй раз не открывается.
Есть предположение, что это химичит метод runLater

Вот окно:

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class Window{
    Stage stage;
    Parent root;
    Window() throws Exception {
        String fxmlFile = "/fxml/sample.fxml";
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
        root = loader.load();
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("JavaFx");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        ((Controller)loader.getController()).stage = stage;
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Подскажите зачем вы каждый раз грузите новое окно?

Может стоит занести окно в переменную, при закрытии вызывать

```
widow.show(false);
```

при нажатии в трее вызывать

```
window.show(true);
```

Соответственно в класс Window надо внести метод

```
public void show(boolean b){
    if(b){
        stage.show();
    }else{
        stage.hide();
    }
}
```

можно сократить через тренарный оператор до такого

```
public void show(boolean b){
    b?stage.show():stage.hide();
}
```

но я их не люблю и мог ошибиться в написании

Comment: Можно, но это все равно не работает, окно также запускается 1 раз